# Random loading freeze in IE on ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, freeze

I randomly have a loading issue after a postback of an ASP.NET page.

When I make any action which leads to a postback, the page hangs in the "loading state" and does not rebuild. It looks like the server is still doing the request processing and did not send back the response. But as soon as I click on the refresh button of the browser, the result appears immediately, which shows that the postback was successfully executed and the response should have been sent to the client.
This problem occurs only with IE. If I use Chrome or FF in their latest versions, no problems.

The problem occurs not all the time and not on one particular click / button / postback. It really is random and it does not matter if the code behind does a lot of stuff or not. Even a simple click on a link can lead to the problem.

One particularity (which I don't like at all but is necessary at the moment in order to render the page correctly in IE) is that we enforce the compatibility mode to IE7 via the following line in the Website.Master

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

- On the client side, we use IE9 32bit on a Windows 7 64bit machine. (Or Chrome 29 | FF  23)
- Development environment is Visual Studio 2012 with .NET 4.5 as target framework for the web-project
- The application runs on a Win2k8 under IIS 7.5, only HTTPS enabled, Application pool is set to .NET Framework v4.0.30319 with Integrated Mode with an SQL 2008 R2 database.

I thought that the problem could come from HTTPS, but we already had the problem when we used plain HTTP.

Does anybody know this problem or could give any advice?